# Trying to use the INDIRECT function within an INDIRECT function and I can't get the syntax to work

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using the following countif formula, inside which there are 2 INDIRECT functions to reference a different sheet

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&W18&"'!H$3:H$200"),   ">"&INDIRECT("'"&W18&"'!A$1")-"8")
```

What I'm trying to do is set up the ability to change the two 'H' in the formula to any column letter from within another cell.  I.e if I change the letter in a Cell from 'H' to 'I', the formula will change accordingly to give:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&W18&"'!I$3:I$200"),   ">"&INDIRECT("'"&W18&"'!A$1")-"8")
```

I am trying to input another INDIRECT function into the formula to achieve this but everything I'm trying doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas as to how this could work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't nest INDIRECTS.  You just concatenate the new reference in the string:

```
INDIRECT("'"&W18&"'!" & A18 & "3:" & A18 & "200")
```

Where A18 is the cell with the column letter.

remember that INDIRECT takes a text string that looks like a range reference and returns the actual range reference.  So no matter how may concatenations one has to create that string, only on INDIRECT per range reference is needed.

Comment: The $'s aren't particularly necessary in a string representation of a cell address; just extra noise.